# Performance/Load Testing PHP / Coldfusion Spreadsheet Web Processing?

Tags: php, excel, coldfusion, spreadsheet, pear

**PHP Pear:PHPExcel** vs **PHP:PHP-Excel-Reader** vs **Coldfusion:CFspreadsheet** vs **Railo:CFSpreadsheet**.

Has anyone done any comparison performance or load tests for large/frequent data-set imports to databases? If so, what do the performance comparisons look like? I'm hoping someone already has specific time/resource metrics.

Also open to any possible alternative spreadsheet processing libraries that can serve up web content. Java/C-derivatives are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem few times ago and it appeared that PHP libraries to deal with XLS were relatively slow. (Didn't try all the one you mentioned here though) We used PHPExcel for our main try and it was really not satisfying.

Our solution was to use Java' library OpenXLS and create a PHP <> Java interface. Not sure if you'd need it in your case or if you can import from Java directly.

Anyway, the main problem about these libraries was always the same : lack of documentation.

Comment: Did you implement GearMan in the interface at all?

Comment: @XaxD No, our process was kind of specific and not generic at all. We created the interface / imports by ourself, mainly using XML files.